# Reload Data in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, refresh

I try to do reload data button. Heres my json:

```
    [
        {
            "name": "AAAAAA",
            "data": "False"

        },

        {
            "name": "BBBBBB",
            "data": "45%"
        },
        {
            "name": "CCCCC",
            "data": "12%"
        }
]
```

My javascript:

```
app.service('service', function($http, $q) {

  var deferred = $q.defer();

  $http.get('names.json').then(function(data) {
    deferred.resolve(data);
  });

  this.getNames = function() {
    return deferred.promise;
  }
});

app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, service, $http) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.reloadData = function() {
    console.log("reloading");
    vm.loadData();
  };

  vm.loadData = function() {
    var promise = service.getNames();
    promise.then(function(data) {
      $scope.names = data.data;
      console.log($scope.names);
    });
  }

  vm.loadData();
});
```

My HTML :

```
    <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl as vm">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="name in names">
            <td>{{name.name}}</td>
            <td>{{name.data}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <button ng-click="vm.reloadData()">Reload</button>
    </div>
```

My data should reload after click function "vm.reloadData()" but nothing happens, my data dont refresh.
Thanks for answers in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. I have remove your extra promise as $http itself **return a promise**..
2. Added provision not to kept request data in **cache**

   ```
      app.service('service', function($http, $q) {
         this.getNames = function() {
            return $http.get('names.json', { cache: false});
         }
       });

       app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, service) {
         var vm = this;
         vm.reloadData = function() {
           console.log("reloading");
           vm.loadData();
         };

         vm.loadData = function() {
           var promise = service.getNames();
           promise.then(function(data) {
             $scope.names = data.data;
             console.log($scope.names);
           });
         }

         vm.loadData();
       });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As per you implementation you are persiting the promise in the service, which is already resolved.

You should define `deferred` in the `getNames()` service methods.

```
app.service('service', function ($http, $q) {
    this.getNames = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get('names.json').then(function (data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `service` code to something like

```
this.getNames = function() {
   return $http.get('names.json');
}
```